# Pastebins (web apps that allows posting snippets of texts) that allow registered users to opt to not include their usernames on specified pasted texts

Tags: webapp-rec

Are there any Pastebins that will allow registered users to opt to not include their usernames on specified pasted texts?

I know I can post as an unregistered user, but I want the management and ability to delete pasted texts functionalities that come with a registered Pastebin user, with an added option of not showing my username on pasted texts that I specify.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a service like [instablogg](http://instablogg.com/). It will give you a link to edit/delete the post later and a different link for viewing. You don't need to log in.